# Run Code after Child form is closed

Tags: c#

so I have this code

```
public void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (PccBiometricsHandler.Form1 ShowProgress = new PccBiometricsHandler.Form1())
    {
        menu.Items[2].Enabled = false;
        ShowProgress.ShowDialog();
        ShowProgress.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(MyForm_FormClosed);
    }
}

public void MyForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    updaterAccess();
    menu.Items[2].Enabled = true;
}
```

so after I click Update it will run the child form Form1
which is this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Update Complete";
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Successfully Update";
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
    timer1.Interval = 4000;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start(); 
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.Dispose();
    this.Close();
}
```

so as you can see it runs on a backgroundworker with a timer to close the child Form1

now my problem is that after closing the Child Form1 it doesn't run the MyForm_FormClosed which it should enable menu.Items[2] again and updaterAccess()

I think I'm missing something in my mainForm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attached the event handler before firing ShowDialog

```
public void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (PccBiometricsHandler.Form1 ShowProgress = new PccBiometricsHandler.Form1())
        {
            menu.Items[2].Enabled = false;
            ShowProgress.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(MyForm_FormClosed); //Attached the event handler before firing ShowDialog
            ShowProgress.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`ShowDialog` synchronously shows a modal dialog, meaning it blocks until the form is closed (the following code is not run until the form is closed). Therefore, when `ShowDialog` returns the form is *already closed*.

You can attach the event handler before calling `ShowDialog()` as @Jade suggests, which will work, but honestly you do not need to use the event system at all. Simply wait for `ShowDialog` to return then perform the actions you would when the form is closed:

```
public void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (PccBiometricsHandler.Form1 ShowProgress = new PccBiometricsHandler.Form1())
    {
        menu.Items[2].Enabled = false;
        ShowProgress.ShowDialog();
    }

    updaterAccess();
    menu.Items[2].Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: ah ok. this is more easy another lesson learn'd heheh thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in VB:

```vb
AddHandler ShowProgress.FormClosed, AddressOf MyForm_FormClosed
```

Comment: OP doesn't ask for a solution in vb.net. Plus, if you know anything about the differences between vb.net and c#, you'd know that how you add event handlers is a big one.

Comment: I came here searching for this in for VB but I couldn't find it anywhere and this was the top search result, I thought it may help others that's all.